# Hardening Web Browsers - Detailed Guidance

Tags: web-browser, hardening

Is there any specific and complete guidance on what is needed to harden a web browser given the number of attack vectors possible, particularly given that browsers allow so many varied plugins?

All I have managed to find are bits and pieces of stuff - including basic security settings, but nothing that is well thought out, defensible and complete from an IT Security perspective.

How are IT departments handling this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out:

[ISAE's Application Security - Browser Guidance](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/app_security/browser_guidance/browser_guidance.html)

> The STIGs contain technical guidance to "lock down" information systems/software that might otherwise be vulnerable to a malicious computer attack.

Comment: thanks! I am actually very familiar with the STIGs. Is that the extent of guidance for web browsers or do you know of other stuff? Regards.

Comment: To be honest what I see from orgs that are concerned about employees catching something bad from Internet browsing is to train those users (more often the high-visibility or high-value individuals) to use throwaway VMs for general Internet browsing.  I am guessing that is because it is a cheaper or easier solution.